# ImportError from file to file of the same folder in ROS Noetic package

Tags: python-3.x, import, ros, realsense, pcl

I tried to start a semantic mapping script on python 3.8 in ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04. The source folder is https://github.com/ExistentialRobotics/SSMI/tree/main 
There are two files in the same folder:
`semantic_sensor.py` - to receive info from camera (rgb, depth, semantic) and via PCL (Point Cloud Library) make a SemanticPCLGenerator class
`semantic_sensor_node.py` - to take the class from `semantic_sensor.py` and make a semantic map
Both scripts may be found here (not to overload the message): https://github.com/ExistentialRobotics/SSMI/tree/main/SSMI-Mapping/scripts

When I start the ros package with this scripts I receive 
`process[semantic_cloud-1]: started with pid [51614] process[semantic_octomap-2]: started with pid [51615] [ INFO] [1701269714.376682262]: Semantic octomap generated! Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/s/test_f/devel/lib/semantic_octomap/semantic_sensor_node.py", line 15, in <module> exec(compile(fh.read(), python_script, 'exec'), context) File "/home/s/test_f/src/SSMI-Mapping/scripts/semantic_sensor_node.py", line 17, in <module> from semantic_sensor import PointType, SemanticPclGenerator ImportError: cannot import name 'PointType' from 'semantic_sensor' (/home/s/test_f/devel/.private/semantic_octomap/lib/semantic_octomap/semantic_sensor.py) [semantic_cloud-1] process has died [pid 51614, exit code 1, cmd /home/s/test_f/devel/lib/semantic_octomap/semantic_sensor_node.py __name:=semantic_cloud __log:=/home/s/.ros/log/ffe73552-8ec6-11ee-8488-cfc925150467/semantic_cloud-1.log]. log file: /home/s/.ros/log/ffe73552-8ec6-11ee-8488-cfc925150467/semantic_cloud-1*.log`

I've got a husky robot with realsense D435,got a topic with RGB, with Depth and added a Semantic topic with semantic NN, the topics are okey and the messages can be seen via RVIZ

I tried to start scripts without ros package, just run them manually. It seems to me, that scripts are working, althought, no map was generated. At least, I have not receive the mentioned above error. 
Tried to add `__init__.py` in folder and ran as a ros a package - didn't help.
Tried to follow the ROS tutorial step-by-step from here - http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile - didn't help.

Comment: How are you trying to launch the ROS node? `rosrun`? `roslaunch`? And have you verified the package built correctly?

Comment: Hello! I tried to start this node via `roslaunch`. The building process was "okey", no errors and warnings. Sourced the environment too. 
I also tried just to run this node without any publishing info (no semantic incoming info), and the output was like "everything is fine", which here means, that the import process went fine.
Tried to start a robot node and this node as well as in one package and in separate.
I think there may be some problem with publishing rate (images are not aligned), but not quite sure how to test this hypothesys.